# Choosing columns based on their name

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have the following list:

```
{{A, B, C, D}, {1, Sin[1], Cos[1], Tan[1]}, {2, Sin[2], Cos[2], 
  Tan[2]}, {3, Sin[3], Cos[3], Tan[3]}, {4, Sin[4], Cos[4], 
  Tan[4]}, {5, Sin[5], Cos[5], Tan[5]}}
```

I would like to be able to chose one column, for instance column A, as a x-coordinate and another column, for instance column C, as a y-coordinate to plot them.

How can I make this ? I really want to chose the columns based on their name.

Comment: Have you tried anything? You could use `Position`, or Transpose and then `Cases`, or convert it first  to an `Association`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I really want to chose the columns based on their name.

You should make a `Dataset[]` instead:

```
ds = Dataset[AssociationThread[{"A", "B", "C", "D"}, #] & /@
             {{1, Sin[1], Cos[1], Tan[1]}, {2, Sin[2], Cos[2], Tan[2]},
              {3, Sin[3], Cos[3], Tan[3]}, {4, Sin[4], Cos[4], Tan[4]},
              {5, Sin[5], Cos[5], Tan[5]}}];

ds[ListLinePlot, {"A", "C"}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactley what I was looking for ! :))